# Keeps saying my passwords dont match

Tags: php

My login system works fine but as a small project, I cannot get my password update to work.

Could someone please try to read over the code and see if they can see the error I have caused? It could be something simple that I'm missing by looking at it so long.

So what is the error I am getting? When I type in the password I logged in with to update on the `$OLDPASSWORD` it keeps giving me the `$OLDPASSWORD` result of that my old password does not match what it was on the database even though it does.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("setup.php");
include("top.php");

$action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

$names = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM userdb WHERE username = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . '"') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($names);

if($action == "") {

echo "<form action=http://www.sentuamessage.com/changepassword.php?action=password method=POST>
<div align = center>
<table border=0 width=34% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr>
        <td width=162>Old Password</td>
        <td><input type=password name='oldpassword'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=162 height=5></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=162>New Password</td>
        <td><input type=password name='newpassword'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=162 height=5></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=162>Confirm New Password</td>
        <td><input type=password name='repeatnewpassword'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=162 height=5></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=162>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <p align=right><input type=submit name =submit value=submit></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>";

include("bottom.php");
exit;
}

if($action == "password") {

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
     echo "<p align=center>You have to be logged in to change your password. Please <a href=http://www.sentuamessage.com/login.php>login</a></p>";
}
else
{ 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
$newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);


$repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);

$queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM userdb WHERE username='$row[name]'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$rownew = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
$oldpassworddb = $rownew[password];


if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
{

if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
{

$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE userdb SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$row[name]'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
echo "<p align=center>Your password has been changed. <a href=http://www.sentuamessage.com/login.php> Re Login</a></p>";
session_destroy();
}
else 
echo "<p align=center>Sorry your New Password does not match. Please<a href=http://www.sentuamessage.com/changepassword.php> Try Again</a></p></p>";

}else 
echo "<p align=center>Sorry your Old Password does not match. Please<a href=http://www.sentuamessage.com/changepassword.php> Try Again</a></p></p>";
 }
}
include("bottom.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using quotes in most of the places?

Comment: Try pasting this in your database SQL : `SELECT password FROM userdb WHERE username='your_name' AND password = MD5('your_password')` and see what result you get.

Comment: You are not escaping *all* input: what happens when `$row[name]` contains a single quote? Using [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) would circumvent this issue. Moreover, only hashing a password with MD5 is not enough; instead, use a [strong password hashing algorithm](http://php.net/password).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this line.. something wrong?:

```
$oldpassworddb = $rownew[password];
```

Should it be?:

```
$oldpassworddb = $rownew['password'];
```

Comment: No, the form without quotes is allowed, though discouraged.

Comment: SOLVED: my fault I messed up my own QUERY

Comment: try debugging your code and database. Turn on errors in PHP etc.

Comment: @user3135306 Then write an answer yourself and accept that one, so others could learn from your mistake.